# cancelAnimationFrame() not working when a conditional is true - JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, 2d-games, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

I'm building a small game similar to [Chicken Invaders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7Ykj8L1ILc) using the JS Canvas. Currently, I'm stuck with the effect of your ship exploding when an enemy hits your ship. I'm trying to create the effect on its own in a separate file.

My idea is that when an enemy hits you, a series of images (14 images) will play in quick succession such that it gives the illusion of an explosion. So I did include the `<img>` tags, I put all of them in an array (using `querySelectorAll`), and then I did create the explosion effect. I used a counter to iterate through the array and display each image accordingly.

But then the counter just keeps increasing so it will eventually result in an `indexError` because it is out of the range of the array. I tried using `return` to terminate the function and `cancelAnimationFrame()`, but both of them didn't work.

The result is that 60 errors per second are constantly appearing in the console (which, of course, will mess everything up) Enough jebba-jabba, here's the link to the JS-Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h7Lvpytm/8/

Here's my attempt at solving this:

```
        const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const video = document.querySelector("video");
        const boomFrames = document.body.querySelectorAll("img");
        let counter = 0;

        function drawBoom() {
            requestAnimationFrame(drawBoom)
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            ctx.drawImage(boomFrames[counter], 0, 0, 200, 96);
            counter++;
            if (counter > 13) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(drawBoom)
            }
        }
        drawBoom()
```

**EDIT: I also tried a `while` loop, but it didn't even display the explosion. This is driving me mad.**

Comment: You'd be better just call `requestAnimationFrame` if this condition is not met or return promptly before if met, rather than storing the id though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/cancelAnimationFrame) takes an id as returned from [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

```
    let counter = 0;

    function drawBoom() {
        const requestId = requestAnimationFrame(drawBoom)
        counter++;
        if (counter > 13) {
            cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
        }
    }
    drawBoom()
```

Or as Kaiido points out you could just not request frame to stop

```
    let counter = 0;

    function drawBoom() {
        counter++;
        if (counter <= 13) {
            requestAnimationFrame(drawBoom);
        }
    }
    drawBoom()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!